# Plucking an enum

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I have scenario where a dish has many votes. Each vote has a type; it's either an upvote or a downvote, all in the form of an enum.

```
class Dish < ActiveModel
  has_many :votes, as: :votable, counter_cache: true, dependent: :destroy
end

class Vote < ActiveModel
  self.inheritance_column = nil

  enum type: { upvote: 0, downvote: 1 }

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :votable, polymorphic: true
end
```

For what I'm doing I just need the vote type and amount of that type. This led me to think that `:pluck` might be useful here. Unfortunately using it in this case would return **all** votes instead of either the upvotes or downvotes:

```
dish.votes.pluck(:type)
Dish Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "dishes".* FROM "dishes" ORDER BY "dishes"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.3ms)  SELECT "votes"."type" FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2  [["votable_id", 4], ["votable_type", "Dish"]]
 => ["downvote"]
```

Right now this is the only way I can get my desired result:

```
def upvote_count
  votes.select { |v| v.upvote? }.count
end

def downvote_count
  votes.select { |v| v.downvote? }.count
end
```

Comment: Yes, so don't use pluck for this.

Comment: Hate to be an over-optimist but is this as performant as I can get?

Comment: `Vote.where(type: 0).count` would return the number of upvote.

Comment: Depends on what kind of queries this generates: `votes.select { |v| v.upvote }.count`. Show the query. I'm guessing that it does _not_ translate to a query shown by Cyzanfar above. That one should be faster (especially with an index on column `type`)

Comment: @Cyzanfar In this case I'm just trying to get a count from a dish instanc vs. all votes.

Comment: @CarlEdwards: "from a dish instance vs. all votes". no matter. `dish.votes.where(type: 0).count`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah I see. I posted the speed difference in my updated question. Am I seeing this correctly where `:select` is faster?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Nope, that is insufficient to draw conclusions about relative performance. Run a couple of thousands queries with dishes having couple of thousands votes. (and measure total time it took to run all those queries) This way, overhead of query processing will take smaller part of the total wallclock time. `Benchmark` from standard library will come in handy.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Will do. Thanks you both for all this insight.

Comment: dish.votes.select('count(*), type').group_by(:type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums provide scopes for each of your possible values.

```
def upvote_count
  votes.upvote.count
end

def downvote_count
  votes.downvote.count
end
```